# Binding Window's DataContext to the window itself in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple dialog window that inherits from Window and I'm setting it's DataContext in XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and here's how I show this dialog:

```
var dialog = new MyWindow();
MyWindow.SomeText = "some text";

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    ...
```

For some reason that doesn't set the initial text of the textbox to "some text" when the window gets created and there's no binding errors.

However, if I set the data context for the StackPanel instead of the Window:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

everything works as expected.

What is the difference between these two? Why doesn't the first approach work?

Comment: The difference is in timing only. While the `RelativeSource Self` binding is evaluated during the execution of the Window constructor, the DataContext is already set when the `SomeText` property is set (so that you would have to fire a PropertyChanged event). The `RelativeSource AncestorType=Window` binding is evaluated later, after `SomeText` has already been set, so when the DataContext gets set, the binding source property already has the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your window to make first case working.

Window itself is not notified about its property (self) being changed and hence dc is not set.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm asking about, see my comment to @Theodosius's answer (downvote is not mine).

Comment: Lol, I posted the same answer 10 mins before he did, whats the point repeating an already posted answer.. @theodosious..

Comment: @szx, I can explain the difference but guess theo will have his word first this time ..

Comment: and the explanation is ---- ( copied ) .... XAML is actually parsed when the constructor finishes executing, because the Dispatcher waits for the user code (in the constructor of the Window) to finish before executing its pending operations.

This causes the actual property values to be different in these different moments, and since there is no INotifyPropertyChanged, WPF has no way of updating the UI to reflect the new values.